# bash function to handle file through symlink : problem with command line arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wrote a little code that will copy files given either their name or symlinks to a given directory.

```
linkcp() {
cp `echo "$(realpath $1)"` "$2"
}
```

here is the file list:

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 users 4096 apr. 30 01:20 temp
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 users 50 apr. 30 01:20 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 users 34 apr. 30 01:20 file2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user1 users 26 apr. 30 01:20 lnk1 -> file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user1 users 26 apr. 30 01:20 lnk2 -> file2
```

This works if I use:

```
$ linkcp lnk1 temp
$ ls temp/
$ file1
```

but not if I use wildcards (I need to move all files beginning with lnk):

```
$ rm temp/*
$ linkcp lnk* temp
$ ls temp/
$
```

If I do:

```
$ arg=lnk*
$ cp `echo "$(realpath $arg)"` "temp/"
$ ls temp/
$ file1  file2
```

I don't know why using `$1` in the function causes a problem?

Comment: I am afraid you have overwritten file2 with file1. Furthermore your approach is not going to work with file names which contain whitespace.

Comment: Right! I understood what happened now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hauke pointed out, your problem is that you're expecting 2 arguments but you give your function multiple ones. The `link*` is expanded by the shell before it's passed to your function so what you're actually running is

```
linkcp lnk1  lnk2  temp
```

because `lnk*` expands to `lnk1 lnk2`.

So, what you actually want is something like:

```
linkcp() {
    ## Save the arguments given to the function in the args array
    args=("$@");

    ## The last element of the array is the target directory
    target=${args[((${#args[@]}-1))]}

    ## If the target  is a directory
    if [ -d "$target" ];
    then
    ## Iterate through the rest of the arguments given
    ## and copy accordingly
    for((i=0; i<$#-1; i++))
    do
        cp -v "$(realpath "${args[$i]}")" "$target"
    done
    ## If the target does not exist or is not a directory, complain
    else
    echo "$target does not exist or is not a dirtectory" 
    fi
}
```

Comment: seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see what really happens:

```
echo linkcp lnk* temp
```

`linkcp` gets more than two arguments but cares about the first two only.

You need something like this:

```
linkcp() {
  local i num=$# tmparray=()
  for((i=1;i<num;i++)); do
    tmparray[i]="$(realpath "${!i}")"
  done
  if [ "$#" -eq 2 -o "$#" -gt 2 -a -d "${!num}" ]; then
    echo cp "${tmparray[@]}" "${!num}"
  else
    echo "error"
  fi
}
```

After testing remove the `echo`.

This takes one argument at a time, determines its real name and calls `cp` with an argument array instead of a single argument. The array can contain a single argument, too. You may adapt the test if `cp` shall always copy to a directory only (and not overwrite files or copy to a new file name).

Comment: There are a few problems in your function. You're not iterating through the arguments, you're iterating through the numbers 1 to `$#`. You will get errors like `1: no such file or directory` if you try to run it. Also, even if you populate `tmparray` correctly, this approach will fail on file names with spaces since you're passing the whole array at once, instead of quoting individual elements. Also, you could simplify your test by using `-ge` for greater or equal to.

Comment: @terdon You are right with the first point. I didn't look close enough at my test output. For the rest: I am quite surprised that you seem not to be familiar with the quoting concept of `"${array[@]}"`... Whether the test can be simplified depends on the exact task. With only two arguments for `cp` the second one may be a file (maybe this shall not be allowed here, I don't know). Only with more arguments the last one must be a directory.